# Youtube video in answer - embedded or as link?

Tags: discussion

Do we want answers with embedded youtube videos or is a link to the Video(s) preferred? Any rule for that? Just found metas about "Video only answers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's up to personal preference. Some prefer to use a link to YouTube as a regular site link [like so](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjhrIsSCcjs). Others prefer to embed them directly.

I think if it's only one or two videos, having them embedded is fine. if you're linking more than a couple of videos, then use the link option to link them properly to avoid your answer from getting too big.

Also remember that a YouTube video *should **not** be an answer by itself.* If the video is taken down, your answer should be able to stand on its own without it.